# Limiting conventional commits only to pull requests

Tags: git, cicd, conventional-commits, conventional-changelog

As part of my CI/CD pipeline workflow, I am considering to make use of [conventional commits](https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/) to auto-generate release drafts in github. The idea of creating draft is to allow the code owners to review release notes before publishing it.

However, I am worried if this could cause following two issues:

1. If we go ahead and create each commit message as conventional commit we would end
   up with a huge log of changes as disconnected information in release drafts which would need to be manually refactored to make any sense out of it before being published
2. Alternative approach, I could think of is to refrain committing changes until all related changes are completed and when done push all related changes under a single commit message. However, this goes against the proposition of CI/CD as it would delay early merges

As a solution to the aforementioned issues, I was thinking of making use of conventional commits only when I create pull-requests to the mainline by the end of completion of a feature. This way I could avoid all the noise in the release draft and yet automate creation of release notes. But I am not very sure if this is the right approach. I would like to know what strategy others are employing to deal with this issue and if the approach I am planning to take is right? Or if we are better off creating release notes manually? Thanks!

Comment: What about setting up a job which you trigger manually ? Generating the release notes looks like part of a "make a release" job, and I think it makes sense to have a manual intervention to trigger such a job.

Comment: My question is more concerned about the noise of huge change logs if were to use conventional commits for every other commits than whether generation of release notes should be a manual or automated.